# MySql calculating hours worked Query

Tags: mysql

Can somebody help me out for this, I calculate it by fetching data into a PHP Array, but I'm wondering if it could be done via Mysql Query.

I want to calculate the time between Start and End action for each person, they could have multiple Start and End actions. The query will calculate the Hours Worked for each person.

```
id  | name          | action   | time
--- |-------------- | -------- | -------------------
1   | George        | Start    | 2017-01-12 11:23:22
2   | Moe           | Start    | 2017-01-12 11:20:22
3   | Moe           | Making   | 2017-01-12 11:22:20
4   | Moe           | Making   | 2017-01-12 11:22:48
5   | Moe           | Running  | 2017-01-12 11:23:12
6   | George        | Idle     | 2017-01-12 13:23:22
7   | Moe           | End      | 2017-02-23 14:33:23
8   | George        | Idle     | 2017-02-12 11:23:11
9   | George        | Idle     | 2017-03-12 11:23:14
10  | Moe           | Start    | 2017-02-24 10:23:18
11  | George        | Proc     | 2017-03-12 19:23:28
12  | George        | Start    | 2017-04-12 11:23:33
13  | Moe           | Idle     | 2017-02-27 17:23:33
14  | George        | Runnig   | 2017-04-13 11:23:45
15  | George        | Idle     | 2017-04-14 19:23:17
16  | George        | End      | 2017-05-18 09:23:19
17  | Moe           | End      | 2017-02-28 19:23:22
```

Comment: You are expected to **try to write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not going to write the entire query for you but I will answer your question as thoroughly as I can without doing all the work for you.

### TIMEDIFF

> **TIMEDIFF()** returns expr1 − expr2 expressed as a time value. expr1 and expr2 are time or date-and-time expressions, but both must be of the same type.
>
> [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Assuming you could hard code the name you are calculating for, and assuming there exists only one start and end time, your query could look something like this.

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(
    (SELECT `time` FROM ttime WHERE `name` = 'George' AND `action` = 'End' limit 1),
    (SELECT `time` FROM ttime WHERE `name` = 'George' AND `action` = 'Start' limit 1)
);
```

Some things to consider.

1. Is there always one start and one stop time for every name?
2. Why is this solution better or worse than the one you implemented this far?
3. How would you make this query work for all names?

Remember the more efficient solution isn't always the "correct" solution.  How efficient do you need the software to be?  Is there anything that is making you try to optimize this?  Which solutions fits your softwares current style guide more?  Which solution is more readable, maintainable, etc?